# dotnet Framework directories different on dev machine than clients

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having trouble running my C# winforms application after upgrading it from dotnet 2.0 to 4.5. It runs fine on my dev machine, but not on clients, even after upgrading dotnet to 4.5.

After a bit of a closer look, I have found that one of the dll's I use now has specific dependencies in dotnet 4.5. A quick look at the VS solution I use to make this dll, shows it uses a few specific files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\ .

But when I go to a clients machine, after installing dotnet 4.5, this folder doesnt exist. (in either "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)").

So - why doesnt the clients machine have it (or virtual machines that I install dotnet 4.5 on)? I get v3.5, and v4.0, but not v4.5.

Thanks.

Comment: They needn't have it in that folder. It can be somewhere else. Why do you care as long as the application runs fine?

Comment: Maybe I should have said this originally, but it doesnt run fine. It keeps complaining that it could not load file or assembly, or one of its dependencies.

Comment: Have a look at http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/procmonanalyzer/

Comment: Turns out my underlying issue is that I had not installed the visual studio 2015 C++ redistributables. I had just upgraded everything from dotnet 2.0 to 4.5, and this one component uses some C++ (the rest is c#).